# ARC with pointers created inside methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have read about the concept of ARC and how we can use the `@property` to define `strong` or `weak`references. My question is how do a define or free pointers when they are inside methods and I would want the memory to be reclaimed as soon as the scope ends such as this

```
    - (void) SomeMethod {
     NSString* databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"contacts.db"]];
     ....
     ....
    }
```

My question is how do I free the string `databasePath` ?

Comment: Take a look at here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH tl;dr you don't have to bother with it, ARC will deallocate databasePath for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless some of the `....` code stores `databasePath` in an instance variable, the memory for the string will be reclaimed as soon as you assign `nil` to `databasePath`, or let the variable go out of scope. You do not need to do anything special for it, because you used `alloc / init`.

The story is slightly different with autoreleased objects, i.e.

```
NSString* databasePath = [NSString stringWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"contacts.db"]];
```

This string would stay around until the run loop gets to decrementing its reference count, unless you create it inside a separate autorelease pool. Therefore, simply setting `databasePath` to `nil` is no longer sufficient to release the memory right away: you need to put an autorelease pool around your variable in order to achieve immediate freeing of memory.

Comment: Let me see if I get this correct So if no strong pointer is pointing to it. The memory that a pointer points to is automatically reclaimed if its allocated by init and alloc ? What about for custom objects ? What is special about alloc and init. I would appreciate it if you could just give me a small overview thanks

Comment: @JamesFranco There's nothing special about `alloc/init`, there's something special about autorelease, when an object gets created with ref count of `1` instead of zero. Autorelease pools get into the picture when this happens, so the object does not always get released right away. That's not the whole story either, because the compiler sometimes tries to optimize out the trip to autorelease pool even for autoreleased objects, but it's a decent working approximation to what's actually going on.

Answer (score 2):

When you declared a local variable, it marks as strong reference by default. And the memory will be freed, when all the strong references to var have become lost. So outside scope, your variables memory automatically is freed, because strong reference is inside scope.